# how to add class to all buttons inside td jqgrid using getcell

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I know getcell method in jqgrid , i.e.

jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getCell',rowId, 'Transfer Price');

I am able to get the values of cell  using this method. I have a column actions where there are two buttons, edit and delete which I have made them on my own, ( I have not used inbuilt jqgrid buttons for edit and delete).

My issue is I am able to add to particular cell , but how to add class to two different buttons in the same cell.

I have added buttons using the following code

```
    index: 'actions', 
            formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                return '<button name = "delete" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="click to delete"">Delete</button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="click to delete"">Edit</button>'; 
                },
                formatoptions: {
                keys: true,
                editbutton: false,
                deletebutton: false,
                delOptions: {
                    url: 'index.php?route=seller/seller_upload/getDelete',
                    mtype: "POST", 
                    keys: true
                    }
                  },
               sortable : false,       
            });
```

I am using grid complete method to add class to the actions column like

```
    gridComplete: function () {
                var ids = [];
                ids = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');

                var items = [];
                var count_btn = 0;
                for(var variable=0;variable<ids.length;variable++) {
                    var rowId = ids[variable];  

                    if(variable%2 !=0 ) {
                        jQuery("#grid").find('actions').addClass('classname');
                        jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setCell', rowId,  'actions', '', 'classname');
                        $('.classname').html('');
                    }

                    if(variable%2 == 0) {
                        //setting id for column
                        jQuery("#grid").find('actions').addClass('used_button'+count_btn);
                        jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setCell', rowId,  'actions', '', 'used_button'+count_btn);
                        $('.used_button'+count_btn).attr("id","id_"+count_btn);
                        count_btn++;
                    }
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Please write in all questions about jqGrid, which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use), and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Additionally it's important to understand the changing of **one** element on the page, like one cell of grid, can follow changing properties (for example position) of **all** existing elements on the HTML page. Thus one should minimize the number of changes. The code in `gridComplete` is very bad for performance.

Comment: The code fragment, which you posted is very strange. Some properties of `formatoptions` looks like you use `formatter: "actions"`, but you use at the same time custom formatter (see `formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {...}`) instead. What you want to use really? If you really use custom formatter then you should modify the code of custom formatter to generate HTML fragment of button depend on rowid. After that you can remove the code of `gridComplete`. Your problem will be solved in the way.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments, I got your point.
I still have some doubts.
If I assign ID to the button using custom formatter, and I delete the row using that button, the ids for other button change dynmically.

Comment: You are welcome! The current code included in your question don't contains assignments of ids to the buttons. The assignment itself is not a problem, but you should be careful in choosing the id value to hold all ids on the HTML page unique. `options.rowId` is the rowid, `this.p.idPrefix` is the value of `idPrefix` option of jqGrid. You can build id value of buttons based on the values. For example, the id of "Delete" button could be `"act_delete_" + this.p.idPrefix + options.rowId` and the id of Edit button: `"act_edit_" + this.p.idPrefix + options.rowId`